# how can i specify my database, csv, rdlc file path to use my vb.net project application on any pc

Tags: sqlite, path, database-connection, vb.net-2010

how can i specify my database, csv, rdlc file path to use my vb.net project application on any pc

Currently i am using following path for my sqlite database:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = C:\Users\Tarique\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Import Shipments\Import Shipments\Data\ImpShpDatabase.sqlite; Version=3"
```